# Power Apps added to Teams tab is not displayed

Tags: microsoft-teams, powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I am working with Power Apps and Microsoft Teams.

I have a new Team. I add a new tab, I choose Power Apps, I choose my canvas application... it flashes for a second, and disappears. No new tab.

Teams created the notification in the channel, I click the link for my app, nothing happens. No errors, just nothing happens.

I add a different app to the same Team, same result.

I go to a DIFFERENT Team, I can add either app just fine.

I have cleared the %appdata%/Microsoft/Teams folder. I have rebooted. I have tried in both browser and Desktop Teams.

Any ideas?